Is there any problem with the /sharing/share-offsite endpoint of LinkedIn? Error Page is being returned when url is accessed
I'm trying to generate links to be shared as a LinkedIn Post through /sharing/share-offsite endpoint.
But, the endpoint is redirecting users to an error page with no detail of what could be the actual error. When a go to the console of the browser, there is more details but it's clear to me what it means.
Error page after the URL is accessed
The URL I'm trying to access is https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://arciomarquessilvates.bvr.li/clique/ec11919198be
The expected behavior is to redirect me to my LinkedIn and show a modal to create a new post. It used to work normally.
